# C++ member function called begin() question

Tags: c++

Assuming that:

```
vector<string> mvec;
```

has some elements on it

Partial code:

```
for(vector<string>::iterator it1 = mvec.begin(); it1 != mvec.end(); ++it1) {  
for(string::iterator it2 = it1->begin(); it2 != it1->end(); ++it2)
```

since:

it1->begin() deference the object and then invoke the member function begin() of that object, which object is it1 pointing to?

String?

Comment: Thanks EVERYONE!! I want to put all of you have answered my question but i can only click one. :O( Thanks again

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since `it1` is an `iterator` for `vector<string>` when you derefence it you will get a `string`.

Answer (score 5):

`it1` is pointing to an instance of the string class stored within the vector.

Answer (score 2):

This code:

```
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    vector <string> mvec;
    mvec.push_back("foo");
    mvec.push_back("bar");
    for(vector<string>::iterator it1 = mvec.begin(); it1 != mvec.end(); ++it1) {  
        for(string::iterator it2 = it1->begin(); it2 != it1->end(); ++it2) {
            cout << * it2 << endl;
        }
    }
}
```

Prints:

```
f
o
o
b
a
r
```

The first iterator gives you access to the strings in the vector, and the second to the characters in the strings.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's the `string`, which is also a container, so de-referencing `it2` would get you its individual characters.

Answer (score 1):

Like others have said, dereferencing `it1` will get you a `string`. It may seem weird, given that `it1` isn't a pointer, but the `iterator` class overloads the `operator->`, in which case all bets are off in regards to what will happen.